# How to set DATE field to CURRENT DATE by default in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have  to create a table like this

```
create table STUDENT (
    fname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE
);
```

...but I want to set `date_of_birth` variable to the **current date** as `default`.

What I have tried:

```
date_of_birth DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This is not accepted as `date_of_birth` variable must be of type `DATE`

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132951/cant-default-date-to-current-timestamp-in-mysql-5-5

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```sql
date DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Comment: Is your syntax right? coz its giving me error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GETDATE())' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE `student` ( `fname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , `lname` 
VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , `date_of_birth` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL );
```